# SwiftでCocoaPodsを使う方法

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

SwiftプロジェクトでCocoaPodsでインストールしたAFNetworkなどを使用したいのですが設定方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 9):

1. プロジェクトに[ProductName]-Bridging-Header.h というファイルを追加します。
2. Build SettingsでObjective-C Bridging Headerにそのファイルパス（たとえばMyProduct/MyProduct-Bridging-Header.h）を設定します。
3. そのファイルにAFNetworkingであれば#import "AFNetworking.h"と記述することでSwiftでAFNetworkingを利用できるようになります。

Comment: cocoapods自体、現在頑張ってswiftに対応中のようですね。そのうちBridging-Headerも自動生成されるようになりそうです。https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/2835